# How do I make some Javascript code execute on load of any NyroModal dialog

Tags: javascript, events, popup, onload, nyromodal

I have some common Javascript which I would like to execute on the event of any NyroModal dialog being opened.

How do I assign an event handler for, say, the 'on load' (or whatever) event of the NyroModal component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the NyroModal's event handlers can be set in its 'options' object, which you can set using the '$.nmObj' function (by passing an object containing the keys/values you want to set).

To handle the on-load of a popup, you probably want the 'afterShowCont' handler:

```
$.nmObj({
    callbacks: {
        afterShowCont: function(nm) {
            alert('Handled!');
        }
    }
});
```

See a full list of events here: http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/#filters

Note: The 'nm' parameter will contain an instance of the NyroModal object, which allows you to alter the content, manipulate the NyroModal, etc.

Comment: wow you really helped him here :o| ... why just ask a question so you can answer it?

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the afterShowCont inside a callbacks settingslike:

```
$.nmObj({
    callbacks: {
        afterShowCont: function(nm) {
            alert('Handled!');
        }
    }
});
```

Or, you can define it in the custum filter like:

```
$.nmFilters({
    custom: {
        afterShowCont: function(nm) {
            alert('Handled!');
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can define it when you're initiating the nyroModal elements:

```
$('.nyroModal').nyroModal({
    callbacks: {
        afterShowCont: function(nm) {
            alert('Handled!');
        }
    }
});
```

**NB** : all of these solutions work with nyroModal V2.